# How do I make these 2 items appear directly side by side on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook, twitter

I am trying to get my Facebook timeline and my Twitter timeline to show up directly next to each other on my website. I haven't been able to figure out how to do it yet. To see what it is like now, it is at the bottom of the page [bustersusa.com](http://bustersusa.com)

I have spent many hours trying to figure out how to do this on my own and I just can't do it. Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bustersgourmetsauces/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bustersgourmetsauces/">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bustersgourmetsauces/">Buster&#039;s Gourmet Sauces</a>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/BustersGourmet" data-widget-id="697564074893127680">Tweets by @BustersGourmet</a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bustersgourmetsauces/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bustersgourmetsauces/">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bustersgourmetsauces/">Buster&#039;s Gourmet Sauces</a>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/BustersGourmet" data-widget-id="697564074893127680">Tweets by @BustersGourmet</a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

[They are on top of each other now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2xSN.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily they are not next to each-other because they are too wide to fit in your container `div`.

They need to both be able to fit into the 980 pixel width of the container, so you the max size for both of them if you want them side-by-side would be 490px.

There should be a way to set the width for both of those widgets assuming you grabbed the code directly.

Answer (score 1):

try this css:

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
float:left;
width:50%;
}
#twitter-widget-0 {
float:left;
width:50%;
}
```